# Can you compare file name only, without extension?

Tags: batch-file, compare

I am attempting to compare the file names of two folders utilizing a batch file.  I also wish to output the file names to a csv file.

Using the for /f loop, I have been able to successfully do this if the file names have the same extension only. Which requires me to cd into these directories and then rename all files (for example, ren *.txt), however, I do not wish to rename the extensions if possible.

```
set file_compare_dir1=Dir1
set file_compare_dir2=Dir2

for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d "!file_compare_dir1!" 2^>NUL') do if not exist "!file_compare_dir2!\%%a" echo %%~na>>"!file_compare_log!\!dat1!.csv"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d "!file_compare_dir2!" 2^>NUL') do if not exist "!file_compare_dir1!\%%a" echo %%~na>>"!file_compare_log!\!dat2!.csv"
```

Because these file name extensions are not the same, this does not work. I have attempted to use%%~na, however this also does not work in this fashion.

Comment: What about `if not exist "!file_compare_dir2!\%%~na.*"`?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I attempted this, however it lists all files as mismatch.  If I was to rename all files to *.txt, it works properly, but I wanted to avoid having to do this if at all possible

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `file_compare_dir1` and `file_compare_dir2` definition. As currently written your code doesn't  meet the [mcve] rules.

Comment: It is not a complete solution to this question, but this might be a hint: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178321/diff-two-directories-but-ignore-the-extensions